# How to remove particular table view item in SWRevealViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tableview, swrevealviewcontroller

**For removing i am using this one .But the problem is after clicking particular table view item then only the item will be removed.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:
 (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
 {  
 if(indexPath.row==2)
    {
    return 0.0;
    }
 if(indexPath.row==3)
   {
    return 0.0;
   }
else
  {
    return 75;
  }
}*
```

screen shot:https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUJFe.png

Comment: Do you want to delete a row from tableview or just want to hide that row for specific duration/event?

Comment: i want  to delete a row from table View

Answer (score 1):

First of all delete the data from your array.

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And then tell your TableView to delete that row also.

> If you didn't remove data from array first and try to call bellow
>   method your application will crash

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft]
```

Comment: i send the screen shot .help me out for this issue
screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUJFe.png